# iPhone app:MpMoviePlayer not playing movie in iPad with ios5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have created my iPhone app in Xcode 4 with base SDK 4.3

In my iPhone app I have used MPMovieplayercontroller and using that I am playing Video

It is playing my video file in my iPod Touch with IOS 4.3 but if I install same project in my iPad with iOS 5, it is showing  black screen only but not playing video.

what could be wrong?

Here is the code
in .h file

```
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;
```

in .m file

```
 -(void)playVideo{
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testbild1" ofType:@"m4v"]];
 moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
UIView *testview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[testview addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
 [self.view addSubview:testview];
  }  

   - (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification  
   {  
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];  
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                               name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                               object:moviePlayerController];  

 [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];  


 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're setting autoplay

```
shouldAutoplay
A Boolean that indicates whether a movie should begin playback automatically.

@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldAutoplay
```

So like:

```
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true;
```

You should also be probably calling `prepareToPlay` and play from the `MPMediaPlayback` protocol that `MPMoviePlayerController` implements

Old Post (should have been a comment):

What version iOS?  iOs 5.1 beta just came out and alters how MPMoviePlayerController works.

You can get details on Apple's iOS beta site but I can't print them here YAY EULA.

---

**EDIT**

Now that the OS is public, here's the relevant documentation (registration -- you might have to pay the $100 as well, I forget...)

- [iOS 5.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_1/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011329) (Search for `prepareToPlay` on that page -- no deep linking)
- [MPMoviePlayerController class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953)

Comment: it is iOS 5 not iOS 5.1 beta.so what are you suggesting ?should I go for iOS 5.1 Beta

Comment: Should I write these tow lines or not                          [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];

Comment: Yes, that's the proper way to instantiate the video player.

Comment: tkone, since the iOS 5.1 SDK was already made public, can you explain/give a link to the documentation that explains MPMoviePlayerController changes in 5.1?

Comment: I see, thanks. I knew about the `prepareToPlay` as it was documented in iOS 5.0, but I was still observing different behavior between 5.0 and 5.1's `MPMoviePlayerController` so I thought I was missing something. Thanks for the updates though!